# PHP Secure Image Upload - Additional code?

Tags: php, mysql, image

This is my code to upload image file to php/mysql server. I have read similar posts and tutorials but mostly were saying they´re not complete.

Is this enough to be secure or what more would be missing?

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]['error'] == 0)
{
$file = $_FILES["file"];

    $file = $_FILES["file"]['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES["file"]['type'];
    $file = strtolower($file);
    $file_type = strtolower($file_type);

    if(is_array($_FILES["file"]['error'])){
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        die('Erro: Only one file accepted');
    }

    $max_file_size = 2097152;
    if($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $max_file_size || $_FILES['file']['size'] == 0){
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        die('Erro: file size exceeded (2mb)');
    }

    /* check if contain php */
    $pos = strpos($file, 'php');
    if(!($pos === false)) {
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    die('Error: image has php script');
    }

/* finfo */ 
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$allowed2 = array('jpg'=>'image/jpeg', 'png'=>'image/png', 'jpeg'=>'image/jpeg');
$ext = array_search($mime, $allowed2, true);

    if(false === $ext){
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    die('FileInfo: Extension not allowed');     
    }

    /* get file extension */
    $file_ext = strrchr($file, '.');

    /* check if it is allowed */
    $allowed = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".png");
    if (!(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))) {
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    die('Extension not allowed');
    }

    /* check upload type */
    $pos = strpos($file_type,'image');
    if($pos === false) {
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    die('error 1: Mime type not valid');
    }

    $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg'&& $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpg'&& $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png') {
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    die('error 2: size mime type not valid');
    }

    //check double file type (image with comment)
    if(substr_count($file_type, '/')>1){
        echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        die('error 3: double type');
    }

    /* upload to upload direcory */ 
    $uploaddir = 'up_files/';

    if (file_exists($uploaddir)) {  
    } else {  
mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777);  
}  
/* change the image name */
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . md5(basename($_FILES['file']['name'])).$file_ext;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error moving image file";
    echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Try again</a>';
}

$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, file) VALUES (?, ?)")) {$insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $uploadfile);

if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
    echo '<div class="register_success">';
    echo "Could not insert...";
    echo '</div>';
}else{
    echo '<div class="register_success">';
    echo "Product Insert success...";
    echo '</div>'; 
}

}
}
else
{
echo '<a href="cad_p.php">Tente novamente</a>';
echo "<br/>";   
echo "<br/>";   
die('No image file selected');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading comments in the PHP manual I found this from a user named **sparticvs**:

> "A note of security: Don't ever trust $_FILES["image"]["type"]. It
>   takes whatever is sent from the browser, so don't trust this for the
>   image type.  I recommend using finfo_open
>   (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) to verify the
>   MIME type of a file. It will parse the MAGIC in the file and return
>   it's type...this can be trusted (you can also use the "file" program
>   on Unix, but I would refrain from ever making a System call with your
>   PHP code...that's just asking for problems)."

Go here and scroll down to see his comment:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

If you are intent on using that solution however here are some pointers:

Use strip_tag() this is on the off chance that someone somehow manages to
get some HTML or PHP tags into your code.
Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

$name = $_POST['name']; This seems dangerous. You're not doing any checks at all.
I would recommend strip_tags again and type validation.

EDIT:
I'll add my teachers notes to this answer:

- Make sure it's not a fake file by using getimagesize() this will
  return false upon failure. (Or something similiar) Limit the file
  size.
- Always check the extension and only allow the ones you want to.
- Change the name of the file or clear the name using
  strip_tags/htmlentities.
- Don't ever save the file directly in your database.
- If the file name has a space in it, encode it properly.

Comment: Ok, please take a look at finfo part at my code reviewed. So, would you recommend to $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']); ? Is that needed to $_FILES['file'] too? Or should I strip the $uploadfile?

Comment: Finfo part is good. Yes I recommend using strip_tags($_POST['name']). Use strip_tags() whereever you want to make sure no HTML or PHP tags can be injected and harm you. I think you'd only need to use it on the filename but you can never be to safe.

Comment: If this is the correct answer then please accept it so it leaves the unanswered section question. If not, is there anything else I can help with?

Comment: I think it could be open to more suggestions

Comment: Alright. I could get my teacher to look it over. He's a leading expert in web development. I'll see if he has time.

Comment: I edited and added my teachers notes. (Not sure if edits show up as notifications).

Comment: First item you mean getimagesize()? Others Items I think are ok in my script. Strip_tags($_FILES['file']) was giving me an array error.

Comment: yeah getimagesize() I'll correct it. You can't strip_tags the actual file you gotta extract the name and either apply a new one to it or just strip_tag() the old then replace.